# VUE JS SPA - Styles breaking when changing pages

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a project in VUE JS where the styling for each page is loaded LOCALLY. (No styles are loaded globally).

Whenever I navigate from one page to another, the styles just crash. Everything gets buggy.
It looks like it doesn't reload the styles or it cascades them all.

When I refresh the page manually, the styles return to normal.

I made a video showing what is happening:

Could you help me?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoeZC8vEQqU

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX4Wg.png)

This problem was already happening when I was loading the styles globally.
I left all styles in local mode and this is still happening.

Comment: Try to import your css file in `<style scoped></style>`  block & Make sure to use `scoped` attribute.

Comment: Please include code directly in your question instead of using images. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15261914)